# NameError: global name 'classObject' is not defined PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a class `master.py` with Glade related Gui. I have a button with a event on it. 
All what i want is to call two other methods from another python file with another class but the NameError: global name 'Airmong' is not defined
error is thrown.

The files are in the same folder!
 master.py file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk
from airmong import Airmong
class Handler:
    airmonObj=Airmong();
    def airmon_clicked(self, button):
        airmonObj.startAirmong()
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("master.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

airmong.py file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Airmong:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def stopAirmong(self):
            result = subprocess.check_call(['airmon-ng','stop' ,'wlan0mon'])
            if result == 0:
                    print "Success stopping airmong"
            else:
                    print "CAN'T stop airmong"


    def startAirmong(self):
        result=subprocess.check_call(['airmon-ng','start','wlan0'])
        if result == 0:
                    print "Success starting airmong"
        else:
                    print "CAN'T start airmong"
```

What am i doing wrong?Thanks a lot

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./master.py", line 9, in airmon_clicked
airmonObj.startAirmong();
NameError: global name 'airmonObj' is not defined
```

Comment: from `airmong.py`? try just `airmong`.

Comment: Same error, i'm sorry

Comment: is your file is `airmong.py` or `Airmong.py`? try `from Airmong import Airmong`

Comment: doesn't work. the files are : airmong.py & master.py

Comment: 1) did you tried `from airmong import Airmong` --> say this in `Master.py` instead of saying `from airmong.py import Airmong`;  2) also try to indent your `airmong.py` file content properly.

Comment: Post the full stack trace...

Comment: i fixed the problem with Airmong is not defined... now error with airmongObj is not defined raised....

Answer (score 0):

Multiple mistakes in your code:

**Master.py**:

1) in `Line4` change content `from airmong.py import Airmong` as `from airmong import Airmong`

2) in `line8` indent body of function. example code of function could be as follows.

```
class Handler:
    airmonObj=Airmong();

    def airmon_clicked(self, button):
        airmonObj.startAirmong()
```

**airmong.py**:

3) remove space before `class` keyword in `line3`

4) add body for your **init** function. example can be as follows. watch no space before `class` keyword

```
class Airmong:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

step by step fix all syntax errors.

Comment: check the edited post. i Fixed all errors (without point 3... there was no space before the class keyword in the actual code). Same result

Comment: i fixed the problem with Airmong is not defined... now error with airmongObj is not defined raised....

Comment: Yes. that is another point you need to fix.. `airmonObj.startAirmong()` replace it with `self.airmonObj.startAirmong()`. Try go through [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/contents.html)

Comment: @TrulyXax is the code working? with this fix. it must work.